# PreFlight Request 404 not found .net web api ; response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: it does not have http ok status

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2

So I want to enable CORS on my .net web API but the client application keeps getting 404 for the options request and a second error:

```
Has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: it does not have http ok status
```

I have followed step by step what Microsoft website outline and I am still unsuccessful.

```js
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Added this line to my WebApiConfig.cs file
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }


I also tried it by adding the headers in the Web.config in the httpProtocol tag file like so: 

<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```html
Try to enable from the web.config file under <system.webserver></system.webserver> like so:

<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

To handle the preflight request error add the line below in the <handlers></handlers> tags:

<add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />


Then in the  Global.asax file, add the following method:

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
  {
     HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works!
This line was not documented on Microsoft's website <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett your welcome

Comment: saved my day too!

Comment: ty you so much, it's work perfectly

Comment: Excellent, was modernising a .NET Framework app with some SPA elements, and this saved my butt

Comment: @kabal I am doing the same

Comment: I have added above mentioned code  but getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.EnableCors();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And in your `api controller`:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{

}
```

If you wanted to enable it per action method, do this:

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get() { ... }
```

Comment: I tried all of the this step by step and it didn't work @Nigel 's answer worked for me. Thanks tho