# Asp.net WebApi - CORS policy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have Asp.net web api project as a backend
and react js as front-end
I'm trying to make an api requests through my React to get or post data from or to the database using the api endpoints i created an the backend.

first time i had CORS error for both GET and POST requests,
then i added this to my Web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, Pragma, Cache-Control, Authorization " />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

now GET is working fine but POST is not working

Get

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string password)
        {
            if (password == "000")
            {
                using (DbModel dbModel = new DbModel())
                {
                    return Ok(dbModel.Provider_status.ToList());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

POST

```
[HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(List<Provider_status> rows)
        {
            try
            {
                using (DbModel dbModel = new DbModel())
                {
                    dbModel.Provider_status.AddRange(rows);
                    dbModel.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return Ok("record created");
        }
```

Comment: i found the solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632435/preflight-request-404-not-found-net-web-api-response-to-preflight-request-doe

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented same but got error for multiple origins. When I pass multiple origins with comma separated then again I got CORs error. So I've implemented Custom CORS policy providers.

I'm having same issue with PUT method. The solution is Custom CORS policy providers.

The [**EnableCors**] attribute implements the **ICorsPolicyProvider** interface. You can provide your own implementation by creating a class that derives from Attribute and implements **ICorsPolicyProvider**.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCorsPolicyProvider : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider 
{
    private CorsPolicy _policy;

    public MyCorsPolicyProvider()
    {
        // Create a CORS policy.
        _policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };

        // Add allowed origins.
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://myclient.azurewebsites.net");
        _policy.Origins.Add("http://www.contoso.com");
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_policy);
    }
}
```

Now you can apply the attribute any place that you would put [**EnableCors**].

```
[MyCorsPolicy]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    .. //
```

For example, a custom CORS policy provider could read the settings from a configuration file.

As an alternative to using attributes, you can register an **ICorsPolicyProviderFactory** object that creates **ICorsPolicyProvider** objects.

```
public class CorsPolicyFactory : ICorsPolicyProviderFactory
{
    ICorsPolicyProvider _provider = new MyCorsPolicyProvider();

    public ICorsPolicyProvider GetCorsPolicyProvider(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return _provider;
    }
}
```

To set the **ICorsPolicyProviderFactory**, call the **SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory** extension method at startup, as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory(new CorsPolicyFactory());
        config.EnableCors();

        // ...
    }
}
```

It should work, But after your deployment if it will not work then Please add the below configuration in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>    
  <modules>    
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />    
  </modules>    
  <handlers>    
    <remove name="WebDAV" />  
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />  
    <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" requireAccess="None" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
  </handlers>    
</system.webServer>
```

After deployment just do **IISRESET** or restart **App pool**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Install the Cors package.

1. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
2. Enable Cors in your WebApiConfig

```
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // New code
            config.EnableCors();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

3. Decorate your controller like this

```
   [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
```

Source: [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: can i set origins: "*"?

Comment: [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")] i added this to my controller, and now GET and POST do not work and i get this error message: blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

Comment: You can add a global policy to your web config like:
 //Global Policies
            EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,POST,UPDATE");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

or 
//Enable CORS for specific controller
            config.EnableCors();

 [EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*")]

Comment: i found the solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632435/preflight-request-404-not-found-net-web-api-response-to-preflight-request-doe